# Diaspora: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oauth2":

Tags: rubygems, bundler, diaspora

After installing bundler, cloned diaspora and changed directory into diaspora. When I try bundle install I get this error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oauth2":   In
>   snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       oauth2 (0.4.1)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       diaspora-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         oauth2 (= 0.5.0) ruby
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
>   only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

When I bundle update I get this error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oauth2":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       diaspora-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         oauth2 (= 0.5.0) ruby
>
> ```
> omniauth (= 0.2.6) ruby depends on
>   oauth2 (0.4.1)
> ```

Anyone can help me in solving this issue? I follow the guide on http://macabhaird.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/installing-diaspora-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-part-2/ to set up diaspora. I currently using ubuntu 10.04.3

Answer (score 0):

I am into the same issue; at the moment I deleted/outcommented the diaspora-client dependency from my Gemfile.

I wonder why

```
bundle install --without test
```

does not work.

this thread was also enlightening for me. [How do I fix this gem dependency problem in Rails 3 (bundler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559863/how-do-i-fix-this-gem-dependency-problem-in-rails-3-bundler) because all these packaging tools gave me the implicit feeling an application could use two or more different versions of a gem at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that two of your dependencies depend on different versions of the same gem (in this case, oauth2). Bundle seeks to resolve dependencies such that every gem's dependency list is satisfied by a single set of gems. In other words, groovehunter's feeling that an application can use two or more different versions of a gem at the same time is incorrect.

Essentially, the problem comes from the fact that when a gem is required, the source files are simply executed in place. If two gems define the same top level constant, you'll experience one of them overwriting the other (with the associated warnings printed to stderr, but without bundler telling you there's a problem).

It looks like diaspora fixed your specific problem in 0d41c9c5f3b4e7a451c603385305fb17779e813f. Updating your dependencies should resolve it.