# Gem dependency conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, bundler, omniauth

I have run into a similar issue as a previous question, that was posted over a year ago.
[How do I fix this gem dependency problem in Rails 3 (bundler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559863/how-do-i-fix-this-gem-dependency-problem-in-rails-3-bundler)

I am new to ROR. When trying to run `bundle install` on an application, i receive the following:

`Could not find twitter-2.5.0 in any of the sources`

I tried to delet my Gemfile.lock. And tried `bundle install` again. And received the output:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    twitter (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.8) ruby

    omniauth (~> 0.3.2) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.7.3)
```

Results from `gem list`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
actionpack (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
activemodel (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
activerecord (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
activesupport (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
addressable (2.3.3, 2.2.8)
arel (2.0.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bitly (0.8.0)
bson (1.6.4)
bson_ext (1.6.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.2.3)
capybara (1.1.2)
carrierwave (0.5.8)
carrierwave-mongoid (0.1.7)
chef (11.2.0)
childprocess (0.3.5)
crack (0.3.1)
devise (1.5.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
excon (0.16.1)
factory_girl (4.0.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.0.0)
faraday (0.8.5)
ffi (1.1.5)
fog (1.5.0)
formatador (0.2.3)
formtastic (1.2.4)
gibbon (0.3.5)
growl (1.0.3)
guard (1.3.2)
guard-rspec (1.2.1)
guard-spork (1.1.0)
haml (3.1.7)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
hashie (1.2.0)
highline (1.6.15)
httparty (0.8.3)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.5.0)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
json (1.7.6)
jwt (0.1.5)
koala (1.6.0, 1.4.0)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
linkedin (0.3.7)
listen (0.4.7)
log4r (1.1.10)
macaddr (1.6.1)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
mini_magick (3.4)
mixlib-authentication (1.3.0)
mixlib-cli (1.3.0)
mixlib-config (1.1.2)
mixlib-log (1.4.1)
mixlib-shellout (1.1.0)
mongo (1.6.2)
mongoid (2.2.6)
mongoid_slug (0.10.0)
mongoid_taggable (0.1.7)
multi_json (1.6.1, 1.0.4)
multi_xml (0.5.3, 0.4.4)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
net-ldap (0.2.2)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-ssh (2.6.5, 2.5.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6, 1.5.5)
oa-basic (0.3.2)
oa-core (0.3.2)
oa-enterprise (0.3.2)
oa-more (0.3.2)
oa-oauth (0.3.2)
oa-openid (0.3.2)
oauth (0.4.7, 0.4.6)
ohai (6.16.0)
omniauth (1.1.3, 0.3.2)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
orm_adapter (0.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
rack (1.2.8, 1.2.6, 1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
rails_config (0.3.1)
railties (3.0.19, 3.0.10)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2)
rb-fchange (0.0.5)
rb-fsevent (0.9.1)
rb-inotify (0.8.8)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.12.1, 3.12)
remarkable (4.0.0.alpha4)
remarkable_activemodel (4.0.0.alpha4)
remarkable_mongoid (0.6.0)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.2)
rspec-mocks (2.11.2)
rspec-rails (2.11.0)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-openid (2.2.0)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sass (3.2.1)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)
simple-navigation (3.8.0)
simple_oauth (0.2.0)
soloist (0.9.7)
spork (0.9.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
stringex (1.4.0)
subexec (0.2.2)
systemu (2.5.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.12)
twitter (4.5.0)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.29)
uuid (2.3.5)
warden (1.2.1) 
will_paginate (2.3.16)
XMLCanonicalizer (1.0.1)
xpath (0.1.4)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.19'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "haml-rails"
gem "sass"
gem "mongoid"
gem "mongo", "1.6.2"
gem "bson_ext", "1.6.2"
gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 1.4'
gem "declarative_authorization", :git => 'git://github.com/opusmagnum/declarative_authorization.git'
gem 'mongoid_taggable'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem "simple-navigation", "~> 3.6"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 2.3.16"
gem 'mongoid_slug', :require => 'mongoid/slug'
gem "omniauth", "~> 0.3.2"
gem "twitter" 
gem "koala"
gem "bitly"
gem "linkedin"
gem "rails_config"
gem 'gibbon', '~> 0.1'
gem 's3_swf_upload', :git => 'git://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'fog'
gem "mini_magick", "~> 3.3"
gem "jquery-rails"

group :test, :development do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'remarkable_mongoid'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
end
```

I also tried the suggestions of adding `gem 'twitter', :git => 'https://github.com/sferik/twitter.git'` to my gemfile but also had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your results from running `gem list`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using version `0.3.2` of omniauth?

Comment: twitter gem version 2.5.0 has been yanked recently. https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter/versions/2.5.0
Does that make any sense?

Comment: I should have noted that this was a previous developers app. I've just been given the task of making some changes to it. So, I couldn't tell you why it is using version `0.3.2` of omniauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is very late, but you inadvertently upgraded the twitter gem, which was yanked as gruzy notes in a comment here.

Just specify another repo, with a tag that's not broken for you and does not conflict with faraday. For me, this was:

```
gem 'twitter', :git => 'https://github.com/sferik/twitter.git', :tag => 'v2.2.0'
```

You probably just replace `v2.2.0` with `v2.5.0`, and the breakage should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the gems in your Gemfile are locked down to certain versions.  This can create problems when doing an update, and when you deleted your Gemfile.lock, anything not locked to a version is open for the latest possible version.  Normally I don't consider it good practice to blow away the lock file.

Instead, you should run `bundle update gemfile_name` to update particular gems.  Running `bundle update` will try to update all the gems to the latest version as allowed by the version constraints.

If you look in your Gemfile.lock file (not the same as `gem list`) you will see the gems, their versions as well as their dependencies.

Based on this, you should be able to find out what loading faraday as a dependency, and try to relax the version constraint.